# createDefaultRequest - invalid templateId specified on createCaptureRequest()

Tags: java, android

I am looking to configure the *camera2 API* from Android to take a photo with the maximum frame rate possible, so I am trying to take the photo without processing it.

Making research I found that the best way to do this is creating a capture request with the parameter **TEMPLATE_MANUAL**.

When creating the CaptureRequest.Builder:

```
final CaptureRequest.Builder capturebuilder = 
cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_MANUAL);
```

I have this error: 
*createDefaultRequest - invalid templateId specified*

*'cameraDevice'* comes from:

```
private CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            cameraDevice = camera;
            startCamera();
        }
        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
        }
    };
```

And the *'stateCallBack'* is called here:

```
public  void openCamera()
    {
        CameraManager manager=(CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try
        {
            String camerId=manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics=manager.getCameraCharacteristics(camerId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map=characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            previewsize=map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                manager.openCamera(camerId,stateCallback,null);
            }

        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you found the reason?